# Get company name based on contact number or company number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to look up the company name, based on a phone number.

I need an SQL query that allows me to look up a phone number that could be both a contact phone number, or a company phone number, and return the company name.

My table structure (simplified)

#### Contacts table

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| id |  Name  |   Phone   | CompanyID |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | John   | 258649864 |         3 |
|  2 | Martin | 258699182 |         2 |
|  3 | Amy    | 296847348 |         2 |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

#### Company table

```
+----+----------------------+------------+
| id |         Name         |   Phone    |
+----+----------------------+------------+
|  1 | Virtual Company Inc. | 7070305030 |
|  2 | Worldwide 101        | 3050101020 |
|  3 | 24/7 Employee        | 5023268293 |
+----+----------------------+------------+
```

I've tried something like this (when trying to look up the number 3050101020) but it does't work (return no rows).

```
SELECT Company.Name FROM Contacts
JOIN Company ON Company.id = Contacts.CompanyID
WHERE Contacts.Phone = '3050101020'
OR Company.Phone = '3050101020'
```

Comment: `SELECT Company.Name FROM Contacts` ? shouldn't it be `SELECT Company.Name FROM Company`?

Comment: @learner there is a `JOIN` there

Comment: Considering the answers given, can you confirm your query does not return data with the given sample set?

Comment: @onedaywhen, I've tested OP's query with OP's data - and it does return the company name! (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, in case there is a company without a contact, or a contact without a company specified:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Company.Name
FROM Company
FULL OUTER JOIN Contacts ON Company.id = Contacts.CompanyID
WHERE '3050101020' IN (Contacts.Phone, Company.Phone)
```

BTW, the original query seems to do just fine:

```
SQL>create table contacts (id int, name varchar(10), phone varchar(20), 
SQL&    companyid int);
SQL>insert into contacts values (1,'John','258649864',3);
SQL>insert into contacts values (2,'Martin','258699182',2);
SQL>insert into contacts values (3,'Amy','296847348',2);
SQL>create table company (id int, name varchar(30), phone varchar(20));
SQL>insert into company values (1,'Virtual Company Inc.','7070305030');
SQL>insert into company values (2,'Worldwide 101','3050101020');
SQL>insert into company values (3,'24/7 Employee','5023268293');
SQL>SELECT Company.Name FROM Contacts
SQL&JOIN Company ON Company.id = Contacts.CompanyID
SQL&WHERE Contacts.Phone = '3050101020'
SQL&OR Company.Phone = '3050101020';
name
==============================
Worldwide 101
Worldwide 101

                  2 rows found
```

You can throw in `SELECT DISTINCT` to get the company name only once. (You get it twice because the company has two contacts.)

And do a `LEFT JOIN` to get companies without contacts, or even a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to also get contacts without companies.

Comment: Why would this return results when op's query didn't?.

Comment: @Lamak, good point. Will at least return Virtual Company Inc - if requested.

Answer (score 1):

For me your query seems to be correct. only possible reason to not getting result is may be blank space present in Phone column. Try to use TRIM function

```
SELECT Company.Name 
FROM Contacts
JOIN Company ON Company.id = Contacts.CompanyID
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(Contacts.Phone)) = '3050101020'
OR RTRIM(LTRIM(Company.Phone)) = '3050101020
```

Comment: sql-server doesn't have a function `trim`, it has `ltrim` and `rtrim`

Comment: So far, this is the only answer that makes sense, given the sample set.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: it would only make sense if there were leading/trailing spaces in the sample data, which I'm not seeing :)

Comment: @onedaywhen what do you think about op's query. is he did any wrong with it?

Comment: The query assumes every company has at least one entry in the contact table. The sample data bears this out. But if the real data had companies  without contacts then it would fail in the way the OP describes. Conclusion: sample data is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `union`:

```
select c.name
from companies c
where c.phone = @phone
union
select c.name
from companies c join
     contacts co
     on co.companyid = co.id
where co.phone = @phone;
```

Note:  This is an intentional use of `union` to remove duplicates.  The use of two queries makes it more likely that SQL Server will take advantage of indexes on `phone`, if they exist.

If you like, you can also write this as:

```
select distinct c.name
from companies c left join
     contacts co
     on co.companyid = co.id
where co.phone = @phone or c.phone = @phone;
```

However the use of `or` makes it less likely that appropriate indexes will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Do an existance test to resolve your problem :

```
SELECT company.name
from company com
where com.phone = 'xxx' 
 or exists (
  select 1 
  from contacts cnt 
  where cnt.phone = 'xxx' and cnt.CompanyID = com.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure for it that will pass only phone number as a parameter
and result company name

Note: make company table as the base table because it has a primary key

```
Create procedure(@number varchar(max))
As 
begin
    If(Isnull(@number, 0))
    BEGIN
        SELECT Company.Name 
        FROM Company
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Contacts ON Company.id = Contacts.CompanyID
        WHERE Contacts.Phone = @number
           OR Company.Phone = @number
    END
End
```